# String indices must be integers, not 'str' when extracting value from JSON using python

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON of the following format:

```
{
 "records": {
    "expiryDates": [
    'date1',
    'date2'
    ]
  }
}
```

I get the above json via an API call and the result of the request is cast into a JSON object like so:

```
r = requests.get(url, headers)
dataJSON = json.loads(r.text)
```

To get expiryDates, I use `dataJSON["records"]["expiryDates"].`
Doing this gives me the error: TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'

I read through various threads on this and understand that I should probably cycle through all the keys to get at the value for 'records'.
Questions:

1. Is the above method not the most optimal way of accessing items within a JSON object?
2. When executed as standalone python code, there are no errors, but when executed within a Flask application, it crashes. Any help in understanding why would be most helpful.

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Could not duplicate once I fixed the single quotes around `'date1'` and `'date2'`.  `dataJSON = json.loads(text)` and `dataJSON['records']['expiryDates']` executed without error.

Comment: If `dataJSON` was a string you would get `TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'`. What does `print(type(dataJSON))` give? What does `print(type(dataJSON['records']))` give? Have you looked at `print(dataJSON)` and `print(dataJSON['records'])`?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: type(dataJSON) returns <class 'dict'>. as does type(dataJSON["records"]). When I execute this as a stand-alone program from within PyCharm, it works. But putting in a function and calling from within a Flask application results in this error.

Comment: Did you run those tests on Flask (possibly need to log rather than print)?